# How can a user access web app by location on Azure

Tags: azure, geolocation

I'm moving a web app to azure and its possible to have multiple locations, for example a user on California access at the US West and a user in England access on Europe the same web app? I'm not talking about failover, but a multilocation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to just use Azure Trafic Manager with geographic routing method in front of the web apps:

[image]

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#geographic-traffic-routing-method